# gnome-terminal new tab dbus

Tags: tabs, automation, gnome-terminal, dbus

I want to run a command (assumedly using dbus-send) that opens a new tab in a gnome-terminal session and runs a command.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ROXTerm and `--tab`

Answer (score 3):

I believe gnome-terminal doesn't have a dbus interface.  [Trustin Lee has a blog post](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2236/) about Opening a New tab/ gnome-terminal via a shell script, I added an extra line to make use of [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to 'fake' the key input, I suppose you can use this approach.

Please note: I haven't tried this myself as I'm supposed to be working in office ;)

```
#!/bin/sh
# Path: /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
if [ "x$*" != "x" ]; then
  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal "$@"
else
  pgrep -u "$USER" gnome-terminal | grep -qv "$$"
  if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    WID=`xdotool search --class "gnome-terminal" | head -1`
    xdotool windowfocus $WID
    xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
    wmctrl -i -a $WID
    xdotool type <your-command-here>
  else
    /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
    xdotool type <your-command-here>
  fi
fi
```